# Desktop.ini files breaking node_modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, desktop.ini

I have a create-react-app project that works well. However, if I let it sit for a couple days—without making any changes—it always breaks, with the error

```
package.json » eslint-config-react-app/jest#overrides[0]:

Environment key "jest/globals" is unknown
```

I'm convinced this is because `desktop.ini` files get created, and somehow they mess up the loading process of the dependencies. The problem gets fixed if I delete the whole `node_modules` folder and reinstall it using `npm install`. But the newly installed dependencies only last a couple of days (until the new `desktop.ini` files get regenerated) before they again break.

I've tried to stop windows from producing the `desktop.ini` files using the registry, but windows didn't listen (I run Windows 11). I've also seen that it is not recommended to delete/suppress these files.

Has anyone dealt with this issue? Are there any manageable workarounds?

Comment: I encountered the same error today; but with python http server; I develop on flask; but for standalone frontend development, I use this simple server hosted on localhost:8000; I have node installed on my machine, but this problem doesn't seem to be specific to node modules; have you found any solutions?